# Build error : Incompatible versions of SQL Server Data Tools and database runtime components are installed on this computer

Tags: sql-server-data-tools

I have a Visual Studio 2012 project that reports an error from msbuild when trying to publish the database from the command line:

> Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets(390,5): Build error :
>   Incompatible versions of SQL Server Data Tools and database runtime
>   components are installed on this computer.

I have checked and installed all updates for VS2012 SSDT and everything is up to date.

Comment: I have the same problem except that your fix doesn't work.

First, the path is correctly referring to 11.0. Then, SSDT for VS2010 is obsolete and can't be installed. I'm not sure it would even work. 

In any case, I still have the issue. Have you heard anything else on this problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The trick was to install SSDT updates for Visual Studio 2010 - despite the fact that my solution was running in VIsual Studio 2012. The solution was upgraded from 2010 so perhaps that is why there is the dependency.

Another clue was in the path to the build target - v10 not v11

> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\SSDT\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets(390,5): [error message followed]

Comment: My solution was not upgraded from 2010 to 2012, yet this trick worked for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue but without the version v10/v11 being the issue.

To fix this problem, I closed Visual Studio 2012 then went into Programs and Features and did a repair of the following installer:

- Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools - enu (11.1.41025.0)
- Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools - Database Projects - Web installer entry point

Restart Visual Studio and compile again. Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Downloading and running the latest installer for Visual Studio 2012 fixed this issue for me.